# How can I change the color cell based on the value when there are other cells with text in latex?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I'm trying to change the background color of some cells that have values above some limit. For example, if the cell value is higher than 2, then the cell background color should be red.
I think I'm very close because I can do it when the table only has numbers. The problem is I don't know how to do it when my table has some cells that contain text and others with numbers.

What I can do:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell}

%The min, mid and max values
\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{0.0}%
\newcommand*{\MidNumber}{0.5} %
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{1.0}%

%Apply the gradient macro
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
        \ifdim #1 pt > \MidNumber pt
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(#1 - \MidNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MidNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
            \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{green!\PercentColor!yellow}{#1}
        \else
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(\MidNumber - #1)/(\MidNumber-\MinNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
            \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{red!\PercentColor!yellow}{#1}
        \fi
}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm} % box size
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\center{{\textbf{\huge SOME TEXT HERE}} \\Lat: -20.34 / Lon: -40.21 \\}
\caption{Some text here...}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\center
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{*{10}{R}}
            \hline
            %\rowcolor{Gray}
              1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.96 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.37 \\
              1.00 & 1.00 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.95 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.01 \\
              1.00 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.96 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.67 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.00 \\
              1.00 & 0.98 & 0.95 & 0.90 & 0.78 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.08 & 0.01 & 0.00 \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

What I want to do is something similar to:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{collcell}

%The min, mid and max values
\newcommand*{\MinNumber}{0.0}%
\newcommand*{\MidNumber}{0.5} %
\newcommand*{\MaxNumber}{1.0}%

%Apply the gradient macro
\newcommand{\ApplyGradient}[1]{%
        \ifdim #1 pt > \MidNumber pt
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(#1 - \MidNumber)/(\MaxNumber-\MidNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
            \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{green!\PercentColor!yellow}{#1}
        \else
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\PercentColor}{max(min(100.0*(\MidNumber - #1)/(\MidNumber-\MinNumber),100.0),0.00)} %
            \hspace{-0.33em}\colorbox{red!\PercentColor!yellow}{#1}
        \fi
}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\ApplyGradient}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm} % box size
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\center{{\textbf{\huge SOME TEXT HERE}} \\Lat: -20.34 / Lon: -40.21 \\}
\caption{Some text here...}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\center

        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{*{10}{R}}
            \hline
            %\rowcolor{Gray}
             \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text} & \textbf{text}
              \textbf{Hs} & 1.00 & 1.00 & 1.00 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.96 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.37 \\
              \textbf{Tp} & 1.00 & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.95 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.01 \\
              \textbf{Wind Spd.} & 0.99 & 0.98 & 0.96 & 0.90 & 0.82 & 0.67 & 0.37 & 0.14 & 0.00 \\
              \textbf{Wind Dir.} & 0.98 & 0.95 & 0.90 & 0.78 & 0.61 & 0.37 & 0.08 & 0.01 & 0.00 \\
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Theoretically, the only difference would be to include some cells with text rather than numbers.

Someone could help me?
I know maybe this question is easy for someone more experienced, but for a latex beginner like me, it's a challenge.